# method click doesnt work

Tags: jquery, html

When clicking a button then a dataTable is populated from database. I want to jump programmatically to the div containing that dataTable in the click of the button. Here is what I tried ( but I didnt work ) :

```
...
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" ><input name="btnValider" id="btnValider" type="button" value="Valider"  class="btn btn-blue"/><a id="jump_to_result" href="#result"></a></td>
</tr>
...
$(document).ready(function()  {

    $("#btnValider").click(function() {

        getDataFromDb(); // populates dataTable

        $("#box_sidemenu").height($(document ).height() - $("#branding").height() - 100);

        $("#jump_to_result").click(); // go to the dataTable's anchor ( doesnt work )

    });

});
```

So how to go to the anchor "#result" ?

Comment: use trigger() method for do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with this:

```
var o = $("#jump_to_result").attr('href');
$(document).scrollTop($(o).offset().top);
```

---

As you know the `id` of the `a` so just get the `href` attribute value and set the `document`'s `scrollTop()` value with the element's `#result`'s scrollTop.

---

#### [A short demo of it.](http://jsfiddle.net/h3ACt/)

---

The code says that `$(document).scrollTop(` scroll the document to the `$(o).offset().top);` of the anchor next to the button with an id `#jump_to_result`

---

Or use this if you want little animated way:

```
var o = $("#jump_to_result").attr('href');
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(o).offset().top
}, 800);
```

#### [Demo with a smooth movement.](http://jsfiddle.net/h3ACt/1/)

Comment: @pheromix my bad i should have used `.offset().top` instead of `.scrollTop()` see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnValider").click(function() {

    //getDataFromDb(); // populates dataTable

    $("#box_sidemenu").height($(document ).height() - $("#branding").height() - 100);
   // following code commented 
   // $("#jump_to_result").click(); // go to the dataTable's anchor ( doesnt work )
   // redirection made here 
   window.location = $("#jump_to_result").attr('href');
   });  

});
</script>
```

Comment: yes , it works ! but like much the answer with jquery animation ! thankx anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following somewhere in you html?

```
<a name="result"></a>
```

Does the above code have time to be generated before the click? Maybe wait a little?

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#jump_to_result").click();
}, 200);
```

**EDIT 1:**

I might got a solution for you but it's not what your asking for but might solve the problem.

```
$(document).scrollTop($("#scrollHere").offset().top);
...
<a id="scrollHere"></a>
```

Comment: there is no time generator involved !